# Protect a sheet results in a corrupt workbook

Tags: apache-poi

I want to copy an Excel Workbook with apache poi. The copy must be protected but the user should be able to resize the columns. I prepared a template and picked "columns format" on the first sheet in the template. When I use the following snippet

```
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                new File(DIR, "template.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(is);
            XSSFSheet s = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            s.protectSheet("");
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(DIR, "test.xlsx"));
            wb.write(os);
            os.close();
```

I get a corrupt Excelsheet. I use apache poi 3.8 and Excel 2007.

Is there a workaround for protecting the sheets but allow to resize the columns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

stephan

Comment: same here. I'm currently dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just solved this problem. You can use the following code:

//just initialize these
XSSFWorkbook xwb; 
XSSFSheet xsheet;

xsheet.protectSheet("1234");
xsheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection().setFormatColumns(false);
xsheet.enableLocking();
xwb.lockStructure();

Hope this helps somebody in the future! :D